# Pyspark streaming write in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, spark-streaming

Is there a way to write through Spark Streaming, reading from kafka and write in ElasticSearch? 
I tried something like... As explained in the ElasticSearch docs (with very little documentation regarding pyspark):

```
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", appName="TwitterStreamKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, batchIntervalSeconds)
topic = url_topic

tweets = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
tweets.pprint()

conf = {"es.resource": "credentials/credential"}  # assume Elasticsearch is running on localhost defaults
if tweets.count() > 0:
    tweets.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
    path='-',
    outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf=conf))

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

But it doesn't work. The error is:

```
17/11/10 17:16:35 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse; Bailing out..
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.processBulkResponse(RestClient.java:251)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:222)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:244)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.close(RestRepository.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.doClose(EsOutputFormat.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.close(EsOutputFormat.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/11/10 17:16:35 ERROR SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter: Task attempt_20171110171633_0003_r_000000_0 aborted.
17/11/10 17:16:35 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopMapReduceWriter.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the command I use to execute it:

```
spark-submit --jars elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.4.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar es_spark_write.py
```

I am using spark 2.2.0
The messages from Kafka are key-message json like these:

> `(u'urls', u'{"token": "secret_token", "count": 2443}')`

Comment: What is the error in the output? Where is the elasticsearch jar located?

Comment: @mkaran I updated the question with further information. Elastichsearch is in localhost and all the jars are in the same folder

Comment: Thanks, I asume  `conf = {"es.resource": "credentials/credential"}` credentials/credential is the index/type? Ok, first check that you can read from es and that the configs are ok by `rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat", "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=dict_conf)
print rdd.first()`

Comment: configs are okay and I can read from ES... But still no luck for writing in ES. :(